# "silk purses out of a sow's ears"

Tags: idioms, pejorative-language

Yesterday I posted a question(https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186907/how-do-expert-writers-avoid-using-i-when-they-mean-to-address-themselves-in) and received a good  yet insult-ish like answer. I'm not a native so I am just wondering if the idiom **You can't make silk purses out of a sow's ear** either **is** insulting or **borders on** being so.

thanks every one

Comment: It is a common idiom which you can easily google.

Comment: @medica: ... so?

Comment: It was intended as an insult towards the style of writing being discussed.  The answer accepted below doesn't really capture the idea being presented in the comment you referenced.  Instead, the point in this case is that it is **impossible** to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.  The parallel being that it is impossible to make artful use of the first person, if using the first person is artless.  Please note that I do not support the assertion, rather I am helping to clarify its understanding.

Comment: @Lumberjack ; Yes, the first sentence of your comment goes the clearest way to put the bottom line, I guess. thanks.
As to the answer, I accepted it, because comments can't be accepted! His further comment was helpful and to-the-point.

Comment: @itsme I'm sorry that I wrote my comment in a way that it could be construed as criticizing you.  It was not my intention, although one's intention matters little once the words are on the page.  The second sentence of my comment was useless, rude and should have been omitted.  Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can have a positive or negative connotation based on the context.  Let us take a couple of examples.  One involves people and the other involves inanimate things (on the side being compared to sow's ears).

Assume that you're the manager of a team of athletes.  You're targeting a big championship but your team is mediocre.  If you win, you could say, "I made silk purses of a sow's ear."  If you lose, you could say, "I did my best to make silk purses of a sow's ear."  In both cases, your effort indicated may hold a positive meaning but the team is obviously referred to as sub-par, and so may be considered somewhat insulting to them.

Assume you are making a magnificent chair out of broken pieces of wood.  In this case, you have made silk purses of a sow's ear but there is no insult involved, just excellent craftsmanship.

**Sources/Further Reading:**

- The Expression: make a silk purse of a sow's ear (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_a_silk_purse_of_a_sow%27s_ear)
- Proverbial Version: you can't make a silk purse of a sow's ear (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/you_can%27t_make_a_silk_purse_of_a_sow%27s_ear)

Comment: (I just care/wonder to learn:) Considering the context in this particular case, I have been contemplating some unspoken element of such implication within the idiom that "it's too elusive for a non-native to spot and appreciate linguistic points of this exactness and delicacy."

Comment: @Itsme, in the answer given to your question on how experts avoid using "I", the answer's author Ben M merely seems to imply that form doesn't really matter as much as the caliber of the writer's work.  In other words, if the work (or the writer) is inherently great, then whether or not "I" is used doesn't matter.  Similarly, if the work (or the writer) is lousy, then the usage/avoidance of "I" really doesn't matter.  So, no insult is apparent to the person asking the question in this case.  Though there are some who act rude, a majority of the members here are pretty nice and understanding.

Comment: The bullet-point format gives the impression that there are two distinct 'forms of the expression', the 'idiomatic' and the 'proverbial'. 'The expression' is **always** idiomatic (there being no people who need telling that their attempts to actually convert female pigs' outer ears into fashion accessories are doomed to failure); the proverb is merely the form often used to patronise ('You can't ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, just edited the bullets to distinguish the expression from its proverbial form.

Comment: They're _both_ 'idiomatic'; the expression always is, in all its slight variants. The proverbial version is just the one that '[is a well-known expression and] expresses a truth based on common sense or the practical experience of humanity' (Wikipedia). So 'You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear' is both idiomatic (having a meaning other than the literal one) and a proverb; 'Bill's trying to make a silk purse out of a sow's ear' isn't the proverbial version but is still idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, noted and voted up.  I've edited it again to make it conform to your guidance.  Feel free to let me know if any further changes are needed.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Your first comment above was worthy of Doc Mark Sloane. (It would have been tempting to book into Community General Hospital just to experience his gentle manner if it weren't for the fact that the major cause of death there seemed to be murder. The scriptwriters' fault, not his, of course.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I haven't blushed more since my father said I had lost weight!  Thanks!  As for the Van Dykes, I'm a Barry fan though :-)